# Console DBCS issue in eclipse Juno with Liberty 8.5.5.2

Tags: websphere, eclipse-juno, websphere-liberty

I have console DBCS issue in eclipse Juno with Liberty 8.5.5.2 like below(DBCS broken issue)

```
IBM J9 VM���� server01(WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.2/wlp-1.0.5.cl50220140403-1858) ����, ���� pwa6470sr6ifx-20131031_01 (SR6+IX90131 SR6+IX90131) (ko_KR)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: server01 ������ ����Ǿ����ϴ�.
```

However, I could open it without any issue when I checked it with texteditor like below

```
[14. 4. 29   1:24:11:440 KST] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.TraceSpecification               I TRAS0018I: 추적 상태가 변경되었습니다. 새 추적 상태는 *=info입니다.
```

Even I added below options, it's same...

```
-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
-Dclient.encoding.override=utf-8
```

Please give me expert advice how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you first start the server, a launch configuration is created.  You can see the launch configuration by clicking on the Run menu and selecting Run Configurations.  Look under Liberty Profile Server for your launch configuration.  Open it and check the encoding in the Common tab.  Try setting it to UTF-8 and restart the server.

If you want launch configurations to be created with UTF-8 encoding by default go to the Window menu and select Preferences.  Expand General and click on Workspace.  Change the encoding to UTF-8 by clicking Other and selecting UTF-8 from the dropdown.

Comment: This also fixed my encoding issues in eclipse kepler and oxygen!